# recursive function return all the possible paths

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I try to write recursive function which gets an array of flights and returns all the possible paths from source country to dest country.

The function signature in Java:

```
List<List<String>> printAllPathsUtil(String src, String d,List<Flight> localPathList)
```

every object of type Flight contain 2 features `from` and `to`.

I succeed to write the below code and its run successfuly,but I sent to the function one more parameter : String help -who store the source country.

```
public List<List<String>> printAllPathsUtil(**String help**,String src, String d,List<Flight> localPathList)
```

I would appreciate it if someone could please find a way how to use the function without the extra parameter,and show in the code.

**Note**:I implemented the classes in a minimal way just to have parameters to send to the function, therefore there is no get and set in the classes.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class flligth {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
    Flight f1 = new Flight("ISRAEL","ROMANIA");
    Flight f2 = new Flight("ISRAEL","HOLAND");
    Flight f3 = new Flight("ISRAEL","LONDON");
    Flight f4 = new Flight("ISRAEL","U.S.A");
    Flight f5 = new Flight("HOLAND","LONDON");
    Flight f6 = new Flight("LONDON","ROMANIA"); 
      
    all_flight all_f=new all_flight(6);
    all_f.addEdge(f1);f1.print();
    all_f.addEdge(f2);f2.print();
    all_f.addEdge(f3);f3.print();
    all_f.addEdge(f4);f4.print();
    all_f.addEdge(f5);f5.print();
    all_f.addEdge(f6);f6.print();
    List <Flight> localPathList=new ArrayList<>();
    all_f.printAllPathsUtil("ISRAEL","ISRAEL","ROMANIA",localPathList);
    }
    
}
class Flight{
    String from;
    String to;
    public Flight(String from ,String to){
       this.from=from;
       this.to=to;
    }

    public void print()
    {
     System.out.print(from+" ");
     System.out.println(to);
    }
    
}
class all_flight{
    static int current=0;
    // adjacency list
    public ArrayList<Flight> f;
    int index;
    // Constructor
    public all_flight(int index){
    this.index=index;
    initFlight();
    }
    // utility method to initialise
    // f list
    private void initFlight()
    {
        f = new ArrayList<Flight>();
        
    }
    // add edge from u to v
    public void addEdge( Flight path)
    {
        // Add to list.
        f.add(path);
    }
    public List<List<String>> printAllPathsUtil(String help,String src, String d,List<Flight> localPathList)
    {
       Flight now = f.stream()
       .filter(a -> a.from.equals(src)).findFirst()
      .orElse(new Flight("no from","no to"));
       if(now.from.equals("no from")){ 
           f.remove(0);
           localPathList.clear();
           if(!(f.isEmpty())){
              return printAllPathsUtil(help,f.get(0).from,d,localPathList);  
           }
           return null;
       }
      
         localPathList.add(now);
        
       if(localPathList.get(localPathList.size()-1).to.equals(d) 
         && localPathList.get(0).from.equals(help)){
               
           
        System.out.println("the path is :");
        printPath(localPathList);
        }
      return printAllPathsUtil(help,now.to,d,localPathList);    
     }


    private static void printPath(List<Flight> path)
    {
        for(Flight v : path)
        {
            v.print();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
   
}
```

Comment: Your method `printAllPathsUtil` always returns null if I'm not mistaken...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you invoke the `printAllPathsUtil()` function, you're passing the same value of `help` each time. Since the property stays constant for each recursive call, you can simply remove it from the parameters.

Instead, you can create a class attribute `origin`, and replace the usage of `help` in the function with `self.origin`.

Answer (score 0):

If `localPathList` is empty, then `help` is `src`. Otherwise, it's `localPathList.get(0).from`.